# 2 базы данных Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Могу ли я одновременно работать с двумя базами данных в Yii2? Если да, то подскажите на примере пожалуйста!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Да. Вот короткий перевод ответа с английского StackOverflow, который поможет Вам.
(оригинальные вопросы и ответ тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254540/yii-2-0-multiple-database-connection)

Для начала Вам необходимо создать по компоненту для каждого подключения:

```
return [
'components' => [
'db1' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1name',
    'username' => 'db1username',
    'password' => 'db1password',
],
'db2' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2name',
    'username' => 'db2username',
    'password' => 'db2password',
    ],
],
];
```

Потом в коде своего приложения в моделях `ActiveRecord` Вам необходимо переопределить метод `getDb()`.

```
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db1;
}

//db2
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db2;
}
```

Модели, в которых Вы переопределили метод `getDb()`, указав db1 как соединение с базой, будут получать данные из базы db1, и наоборот:

```
ModelName::find()->select('*')->all();
```